# Problem inserting row into oracle

Tags: java, oracle, insert

Any idea why this doesn't work?

The name of the table is `TESTTABLE` with just one column called `TEST_COLUMN` which is the primary key. I'm sure it is something dumb, but thought i'd ask.
I'm already connected to the database so i didn't worry about providing that code

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String test = "test";
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (TEST_COLUMN) VALUES (" + test + ")");
```

gives me this error

```
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that is a varchar column, so try:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (TEST_COLUMN) VALUES ('" + test + "')");
```

Note the single quotes around the data.

Comment: The single quotes definitely nailed the problem on the head. @auwall You should  look into using [`PreparedStatement`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)to help avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @auwall: Character data constants in Oracle must be enclosed in single quotes, which is what you're feeding Oracle with this statement. Generally speaking, building dynamic statements this way in Oracle is a Bad Idea, both for the reason @pickypg states as well as performance issues. You should use bind variables whenever possible.

Comment: ok i will look into that now. question though. I obtained a statement from connection.createStatement(); How do i obtain a PreparedStatement?

Comment: @auwall: From the same conneciton. Just call prepareStatement().

Comment: Thank, until 20 minutes ago i had never used anything of this sort and now it's working perfect.